# Angular 2 unit tests: How to override a single provider in TestBed (for unit tests for a service, not a component, with service dependencies)?

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I have:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            DocumentsLoaderSvc,
           { provide: MgrSvc, useClass: MockMgrSvc },
           { provide: URLLoaderSvc, useClass:  MockURLLoaderSvcWhenData}
        ]
    });
});
```

How do I override URLLoaderSvc with another mock, in an "it" case with its own unique requirement? Is there something like TestBed.overrideProvider... Right now, I have each it statement in its own "describe", with its own beforeEach.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this question or did you figure out a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your best bet is to just make the mock configurable to suit the needs of different test cases. Keep it as an instance and use `useValue` instead of `useClass`

```
let urlLoderSvc: URLLoaderSvc;

beforeEach(() => {
  urlLoaderSvc = new URLLoaderSvc();

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     providers: [
        DocumentsLoaderSvc,
        { provide: MgrSvc, useClass: MockMgrSvc },
        { provide: URLLoaderSvc, useValue: urlLoaderSvc }
     ]
  });
});
```

Now in your `it` test cases, you can just configure the `urlLoaderSvc` instance to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ts-mockery` and `Mock.extend` in every `beforeEach` where you need it. The problem here is that the service at this point is already injected in the component - re-providing it will not update the already injected instance. You would need to create your fixture for every test where you change the provided instances in this case. It is easier to have a flexible mock instance instead which you can configure before every test.

But sometimes it is needed, yes, for example if you have something like a repository service which needs an http service call and this call would need to be tested for success, fail and blocking to make sure that the repo service reacts correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is:

```
let urlLoderSvc: URLLoaderSvc;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     providers: [
        DocumentsLoaderSvc,
        { provide: MgrSvc, useClass: MockMgrSvc },
        { provide: URLLoaderSvc, useValue: urlLoaderSvc }
     ]
  });

  urlLoaderSvc = TestBed.inject(DocumentsLoaderSvc);
  // same for other mock services, e.g.:
  const mockedMgrSvc = TestBed.inject(MgrSvc) as unknown as MockMgrSvc;
});
```